# How to call a method from one statefulWidget in another Widget (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, setstate, state-management

I am trying to run method `doAnimation` from another widget by clicking on a `FloatingActionButton`.
Please tell me how to do this with this simple example. I know how to do this using the Provider package, but the code is cumbersome. How can I do this using Flutter's native methods?
Or, most likely, it can be done nicely with the Provider, but I don't know how.
A similar question has already been asked, but the second version of flutter and dart has already been released.
State management difficulties are probably the biggest newbies problem.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: MyAnimation(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          //TODO! error is here
          _MyAnimationState().doAnimation();
          //MyAnimation().createState().doAnimation(); // ?
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyAnimation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAnimationState createState() => _MyAnimationState();
}

class _MyAnimationState extends State<MyAnimation> {
  double _height = 250;
  bool _isOpen = true;

  void doAnimation() {
    _isOpen = !_isOpen;
    setState(() {
      if (_isOpen) {
        _height = 250;
      } else {
        _height = 0;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Center(
          child: AnimatedContainer(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
            width: 250,
            height: _height,
            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'My Test String',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              doAnimation(); // works as it should
            },
            child: (_isOpen)? Text('Close Widget') : Text('Open Widget'))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This error occurs when I try to use the class methods in the usual way.

`This happens when you call setState() on a State object for a widget that hasn't been inserted into the widget tree yet. It is not necessary to call setState() in the constructor, since the state is already assumed to be dirty when it is initially created.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually quite simple and doesn't require any kind of package. You can do this with the help of global keys. First create a global key like this `GlobalKey<_MyAnimationState> _key = GlobalKey<_MyAnimationState>();`. Then pass this key while using MyAnimation class like this `MyAnimation(key: _key)`. Now use this key in the onPressed function to call the doAnimation method like this `_key.currentState!.doAnimation();`

Here is the complete implementation.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
    
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
    
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
    
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
   GlobalKey<_MyAnimationState> _key = GlobalKey<_MyAnimationState>(); // declaration of the key
      
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: MyAnimation(key: _key), // passing the key
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _key.currentState!.doAnimation(); // calling the method from child widget
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
      ),
    );
  }
}
    
class MyAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyAnimation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
  @override
  _MyAnimationState createState() => _MyAnimationState();
}
    
class _MyAnimationState extends State<MyAnimation> {
  double _height = 250;
  bool _isOpen = true;
    
  void doAnimation() {
    _isOpen = !_isOpen;
    setState(() {
      if (_isOpen) {
        _height = 250;
      } else {
        _height = 0;
      }
    });
  }
    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Center(
          child: AnimatedContainer(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
            width: 250,
            height: _height,
            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'My Test String',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              doAnimation(); // works as it should
            },
            child: (_isOpen)? Text('Close Widget') : Text('Open Widget'))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you. It works.
And there can be several such keys. But, it seems, it is not desirable to use a lot of such keys.
Anyway. Thank you so much, this is what I needed.

Comment: Small amendment. Private classes like _MyAnimationState can be used if they are in the same file. I had to remove the underscore in my application.

Comment: You're welcome buddy and also I forgot to mention you can use these keys to access  BuildContext as well! `_key.currentContext!`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write the "doAnimation()" in the initState() instead the use of the floatingActionButton in order to trigger this action when the widget be initialized.

```
double _height; 
bool _isOpen;  

    @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();

        bool _isOpen = true;

         if (_isOpen) {
           _height = 250;
         } else {
             _height = 0;
         }
      }
```

Then use the ElevatedButton as the setter of the bool and setState to re-rendered the widgets:

```
ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
                 _isOpen = !_isOpen;
                if (_isOpen) {
                 _height = 250;
                  } else {
                 _height = 0;
            }
         });
            },
            child: (_isOpen)? Text('Close Widget') : Text('Open Widget'))
      ],
    );
```

Your code will look like this:

```
class MyAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  
  @override
  _MyAnimationState createState() => _MyAnimationState();
}

class _MyAnimationState extends State<MyAnimation> {
  double _height; 
    bool _isOpen;  
    
        @override
          void initState() {
            super.initState();
    
            bool _isOpen = true;
    
             if (_isOpen) {
               _height = 250;
             } else {
                 _height = 0;
             }
          }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Center(
          child: AnimatedContainer(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
            width: 250,
            height: _height,
            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'My Test String',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                     _isOpen = !_isOpen;
                    if (_isOpen) {
                     _height = 250;
                      } else {
                     _height = 0;
                }
             }); 
            },
            child: (_isOpen)? Text('Close Widget') : Text('Open Widget'))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

You can also use the Provider to set the _isOpen value with setter function and avoid all these validations on the widget buttons.

Comment: Thank you. But this is not exactly what I needed. Flutter is good because you can do the same thing in different ways. But it was important for me to keep the DRY principle for the doAnimation method.

Comment: You're welcome, I love flutter too, hope you can find the best  way. Have a great day Bro =D